# What is the result of $x^{\top}A\dot{x}+\dot{x}^{\top}Ax$?

Tags: matrices

What is the result of 
   $x^{\top}A\dot{x}+\dot{x}^{\top}Ax$, provided that $A=A^{\top}$? 
Actually, I wanted to expand $d(x^{\top}Ax)\over{dt}$.

Comment: Since both the right and left hand sides are scalars you have that $x^TA\dot{x} = \dot{x}^TAx$. The question is what $\dot{x}$ stands for? what result you are expecting?

Comment: Assuming that $x$ is a column vector, and $\dot{x} = {dx \over dt}$, then I think your expression is an expansion of ${d \over dt}(x^T Ax)$.  Is that what you mean by "result"?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala yes I mean the expansion of $d(x^{\top}Ax)\over{dt}$.

Comment: @user91011 I guess $\dot{x}$ stands for time derivative of x, Does it mean other things?

Comment: The question is not complex, so It does not requires great deal of expansion, or does it? I thought we can ask any type of questions in this forum. So is there any wrong with this question? @azimut,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $y^T$ for the OP's $y^{\top}$.

Observe that $x^TA{\dot x}$, being a scalar quantity, is automatically symmetric:  $(x^TA{\dot x})^T = x^TA{\dot x}$, and $({\dot x}^TAx)^T ={\dot x}^TAx$ as well.  Now $(x^TA{\dot x})^T = {\dot x}^TA^Tx$, so we obtain $x^TA{\dot x} = {\dot x}^TA^Tx$.  Thus

$x^TA{\dot x} + {\dot x}^TAx = {\dot x}^TA^Tx + {\dot x}^TAx = {\dot x}^T(A^T + A)x. \tag{1}$

Now using $A^T = A$, (1) becomes

$x^TA{\dot x} + {\dot x}^TAx = 2{\dot x} ^TAx; \tag{2}$

is that sort of thing we seek?  It can't be taken much further, I'll warrant.

Comment: how can we prove $(x^{\top}A\dot{x})^{\top}=x^{\top}A\dot{x}$?

Comment: @Ansu:  $x^TA \dot x$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, so it *must* be symmetric; there are no off-diagonal entries!  Just write it out in terms of components, $x^TA \dot x = \sum x_i A_{ij} \dot x_j$ etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @Ansu:  my pleasure, glad to be of service!